# Como puedo obtener todos los archivos de carpetas en python?

Tags: python, lista, aws

Necesito imprimir todos los archivos que hay en 4 carpetas

```
for filename in sftp.listdir('/prueba/prueba/'):
 print(filename)
```

con este porcion de codigo listo las carpetas, ahora necesito imprimir el contenido de estas
alguna idea?

Comment: Publica el código relevante (los imports, para empezar), un listado del directorio en cuestión y una muestra de lo que deseas obtener. Revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El OP pregunta por listar archivos en una máquina remota vía sftp, que es una versión segura de ftp corriendo sobre SSH. Esta respuesta es igualmente aplicable a listados de directorios locales, como se explicará más adelante.

**Escenario**

Obtener un listado del subdirectorio Arduino en la máquina remota Dell, listando sólo los archivos, no los directorios, links y otros casos especiales. El listado debe examinar los subdirectorios detectados.

**Código**

Lo primero es establecer la comunicación con el servidor remoto:

```
import pysftp

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="dell.home", username="candid", password="not-the-password")
```

El objeto `srv` será el medio a través del cual haremos el resto del proceso.

Como hay que recorrer los subdirectorios recursivamente, haremos una función recursiva.

Como la operación de listar directorios es lenta incluso en máquinas locales, usaremos un *generator* en lugar de retornar una lista. Esto permite comenzar a operar con los archivos incluso antes de tener la lista completa.

Como es un *generador*, **no** retorna una lista. Esta instrucción

```
print(get_files(srv, "Arduino"))
```

produce

```
<generator object get_files at 0x7f1dcc0589e8>
```

que ciertamente no es lo que se desea.

El generador debe usarse dentro de un for o while:

```
for file in get_files(srv, "Arduino"):
    print(file)
```

También puede usarse para construir una lista, pero es lentooooooo :

```
lista = [file for file in get_files(srv, "Arduino")]
```

Volviendo a lo nuestro. La función obtiene un listado del directorio recibido como parámetro. Esta lista hay que recorrerla para identificar cada elemento. Si es un archivo, hay que retornarlo. Si es un directorio, se hace una llamada recursiva y se retornan los archivos encontrados.

El código de la función es:

```
def get_files(srv, path):
    """ Generator que retorna lista de archivos.

    @param srv: Una conexion sftp.
    @param path: Path al directorio a examinar.
    @yield Un nombre de archivo con path completo.
    """
    for archivo in srv.listdir(path):
        path_completo = os.path.join(path, archivo)
        if srv.isdir(path_completo):
            for f in get_files(srv, path_completo):
                yield f
        elif srv.isfile(path_completo):
            yield path_completo
```

`srv.listdir` (y `os.listdir`) retornan sólo el nombre del archivo, sin el `path`. Las rutinas de clasificación `isdir` e `isfile` requieren el path completo. El separador de path difiere según el S.O. ("\" para Windows, "/" para Linux), por lo que usamos `os.path.join` para unir directorio y nombre_archivo con independencia de la plataforma.

**Comprobación**

Este es el programa completo:

```
import os
import pysftp

def get_files(srv, path):

""" Generator que retorna lista de archivos.

@param srv: Una conexion sftp.
@param path: Path al directorio a examinar.
@yield Un nombre de archivo con path completo.
"""
for archivo in srv.listdir(path):
    path_completo = os.path.join(path, archivo)
    if srv.isdir(path_completo):
        for f in get_files(srv, path_completo):
            yield f
    elif srv.isfile(path_completo):
        yield path_completo

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="dell.home", username="candid", password="not-the-password")

for file in get_files(srv, "Arduino"):
    print(file)
```

produce:

```
Arduino/Monitor/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
Arduino/Monitor/.git/HEAD
Arduino/Monitor/.git/ORIG_HEAD
Arduino/Monitor/.git/config
Arduino/Monitor/.git/description
Arduino/Monitor/.git/hooks/README.sample
Arduino/Monitor/.git/index
Arduino/Monitor/.git/info/exclude
Arduino/Monitor/.git/logs/HEAD
Arduino/Monitor/.git/logs/refs/heads/linkList
    ... etc ...
```

**Apendice: directorios locales**

La versión para examinar directorios locales sigue la misma lógica, excepto que no necesitamos el parámetro `srv`:

```
import os

def get_files(path):

""" Generator que retorna lista de archivos.

@param path: Path al directorio a examinar.
@yield Un nombre de archivo con path completo.
"""
for archivo in os.listdir(path):
    path_completo = os.path.join(path, archivo)
    if os.path.isdir(path_completo):
        for f in get_files(path_completo):
            yield f
    elif os.path.isfile(path_completo):
        yield path_completo

for file in get_files("/home/candid/PycharmProjects"):
    print(file)
```

produce:

```
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/requirements.txt
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/settings.py
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/__pycache__/urls.cpython-36.pyc
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/__pycache__/settings.cpython-36.pyc
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/__init__.py
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/wsgi.py
/home/candid/PycharmProjects/testperms/testperms/urls.py
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

si necesitás listar directorios y archivos en forma recursiva podés mirar el paquete de Python: **glob**

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('src/**/*', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

Acá te dejo documentación sobre el [paquete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).
Para algo más preciso, podrías seguir la sugerencia de Candid Moe.

Saludos!